# Can't use BloomAI locally

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, bloom

So I just finished installing Bloom's model from Huggingface & I tried to run it in my notebook.

Here's the code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
model_path = "D:/bloom"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_path)
```

and I get this error:

```
DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate xxx bytes
```

So then I went on to google searching and found this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/run-bloom-the-largest-open-access-ai-model-on-your-desktop-computer-f48e1e2a9a32

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: build_alibi_tensor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'device'
```

How to run Bloom locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that problem (and others beyond it) because I was using a more recent version of the transformers library than the one used in the article you linked.  Try using transformers version 4.20.0 as the article mentions.